# Regular expression to split text on space and newline?

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a String that looks as follows:

```
This is line number 1.
[space][space][space][space]\n
[space]\n
This is line number 2.
```

where every [space] represents a blank space and \n represents a new line.
What I would like to do is to split this string into two strings, one that has "This is line number 1." and the other that contains "This is line number 2." In other words split the string on every two empty lines regardless of whether they contain spaces or not.
What I tried to do:

```
System.out.println(myString.split("^[ ]{0,}\\n")[0]);
```

But the above prints the whole string.

### UPDATE

Other things I have tried that also print the whole string and don't seem to work:

```
System.out.println(myString.split("(^[ ]{0,}\\n){2,}")[0]);
```

These all print the whole string as well. Any ideas?

Comment: Do the blank lines have to contains spaces?  Can they just be a single newline?

Comment: They have to contain spaces. Reason why is because I am using a PDF to txt parser, and it adds spaces to empty lines.

Comment: I'll give this last one a shot.

Comment: This can be marked as a duplicate of the mentioned link @ctwheels. Answer was found there.

Comment: @PatrickMuñozVargas you can actually mark it as a duplicate yourself and it'll apply :) I'm glad I could help!

Comment: @ctwheels flagged it as duplicate. Waiting for mods. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Simply enable the multiline flag in your pattern like this.

```
myString.split("(?m)^[ ]{0,}\n")
```

The `?m` character adds a multiline flag you can pass without using Java's `Regex` class.

This should work, not sure if you get the extra split caused by the first line.

Answer (score -1):

I'm just briefly looking through things on a break at work so perhaps I haven't read the question thoroughly enough, but have you tried:

```
System.out.println(parsedText.split("^[ ]{0,}\n\n")[0]);
```

Seems like you are not completely skipping two lines in your code. Once again might be wrong but worth a shot!

Comment: Second empty line may contain spaces two. I have also tried "^([ ]{0,}\n){2}" which works on a python regex tester, but not on Java

Comment: ahh I see, have you tried using '$', I believe it symbolizes the end of a line in Java and might help, perhaps something like ^[ ]{0,}$^[ ]{0,}$